# Are visa exempt travellers to the Brazil allowed to stay for the full 90 day period even if their passport stamp shows a lesser period?

Tags: overstaying, passport-stamps, visa-free-entry, brazil

I had entered Brazil in 2020. I had initially planned to stay for 33 days and I had told the same to the immigration official. My visa-free stamp had the number "33" written by hand on the stamp in a small box next to the word "Prazo".

However, I loved my time in Brazil and I wanted to stay longer.

On the passport which I currently hold, I can enter Brazil without a visa for 90 days and I may extend my visa from 90 days to 180 days at the discretion of the Federal Police.

Before the 33 days were finished I went to the Federal Police to ask if I needed to extend my visa from 33 days to 90 or 180 days. I was told that due to the COVID situation tourist visa extensions were not required or even possible.

This COVID visa extension exemption was temporary and does not apply as of February 2022.

**If I travel to Brazil again for a planned length of stay of 33 days, I am subsequently given a similar stamp with the number "33" next to the word "Prazo" and I then decide that I want to stay for longer.**

**1. Would I need to extend my visa from 33 days to 90 or 180 days? Or is it the case that the number "33" next to the word "Prazo" is just written to indicate the planned length of stay and I am entitled to stay for 90 days as I hold a passport which allows entry without a visa for 90 days?**

**2. If I stay for more than 33 days without getting my visa extended will I be considered as overstaying?**

Comment: Why not avoid the problem and ask for 90  or even 180 days, with the note that you may have to leave earlier if you need to?

Comment: AFAIK, if an Immigration Officer decides to restrict the length of a visa-free stay to less than the normal maximum period, you are not ‘entitled’ to stay longer than the number of days given on entry, and would be overstaying if you did so without getting the appropriate permission.

Answer (score 4):

Policia Federal has the authority to reduce a visitor's stay to less than 90 days if they hold a visitor visa ([Decree 9199/2017](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2015-2018/2017/Decreto/D9199.htm), Article 20). The situation is less clear for visa-exempted visitors, but it's safer to assume they also have the same authority. So I suggest you to consider you got 33 days and ask for extension if you want to stay more.

By the way, the extension procedure is not straightforward (see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172414/question-about-visa-free-tourist-visa-extension-in-brazil/172430)).